# Filter on DATE within custom type?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a custom type in our oracle db, let's call it stamp:

```
CREATE TYPE stamp AS OBJECT(
  timestamp DATE,
  count INTEGER
)
```

I'm struggling with just selecting where stamp.timestamp is between certain dates, and I can't really find that use case in the oracle docs.

I thought "just use dot notation", which didn't work. I did solve that one by finding out I need to use an alias in this specific case, so this is my current state (column is called 'when'):

```
WHERE a.when.timestamp between TO_DATE('2021-06-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2021-06-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Except now it says `Unsupported column type`, which is not very helpful as both the column and entries in the table already exist.

Any idea how to select on a nested date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(when)` to expand your type: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fda61620bf06a6fdb2258a521e59aa65)

```sql
select * 
from test 
where (when_).timestamp_ between date'2020-02-10'
                             and date'2020-03-10';
```

and I wouldn't use reserved/special words as a column/attribute names.

Full example:

```
CREATE TYPE stamp AS OBJECT(
  timestamp_ DATE,
  count_ INTEGER
);
create table test (
  id int,
  when_ stamp
);
begin
  insert into test(id,when_) values(1, stamp(date'2020-01-01', 10));
  insert into test(id,when_) values(2, stamp(date'2020-02-01', 20));
  insert into test(id,when_) values(3, stamp(date'2020-03-01', 30));
  insert into test(id,when_) values(4, stamp(date'2020-04-01', 40));
  commit;
end;
/
select * from test where (when_).timestamp_ between date'2020-02-10' and date'2020-03-10';
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, that really helped. I had indeed almost solved this. Turns out oracle doesn't like the `select *` in combination with this. Your fiddle was perfect for comparing everything to my code :)

Comment: `select *`  works fine too, but DBFiddle doesn't support it correctly, but you can use it in any standard clients, for example sqlplus: https://gist.github.com/xtender/4565b044b29ba0d4ff3c355449bf6d89